# Как подключить Objective-C header к Objective-C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, react-native

Пытаюсь подключить библиотеку React-Native-Nfc-Manager к React Native 0.68

При добавлении `#import "NfcManager.h"` в `AppDelegate.mm` получаю ошибку:
`"Use of undeclared identifier 'NfcManager'"`

Как задекларировать этот класс в стиле C++ чтобы он завелся?

Модуль нужен для добавления Background Reading NFC

```
    // AppDelegate.mm

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
        [NfcManager application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];  // тут ошибка



    // NfcManager.h

@interface NfcManager : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule> {
    }

// NfcManager.m

@implementation NfcManager {
    NSDictionary *nfcTechTypes;
    NSArray *techRequestTypes;
    RCTResponseSenderBlock techRequestCallback;
```

**UPDATE:**

Как оказалось импортировать в *.mm файл не получается. Зато всё работает если импортировать "NfcManager.h" в "AppDelegate.h" вместо "AppDelegate.mm"

В прежней версии импортировать необходимо было именно в "AppDelegate.m"

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось импортировать в *.mm файл не получается.
Зато всё работает если **импортировать "NfcManager.h" в "AppDelegate.h" вместо "AppDelegate.mm"**

В прежней версии, когда использовался Objective-C "AppDelegate.m" при импорте файла "NfcManager.h" все работало. Ошибки не было.

Но используя Objective-C++ "AppDelegate.mm" в него не получается импортировать "NfcManager.h" из-за несовместимости в файле "NfcManager.m" написанном на Objective-C

Comment: Не подскажите почему? Всё-таки вы это как ответ опубликовали, так что вам стоит дополнить ваш ответ дополнительной информацией, это можно сделать кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1427599/edit).